# Нужна помощь в создании тумблера на Python

Tags: python, tkinter

короче ребята нужна помощь в создании тумблера на tkinter (желательно)
я не про Checkbutton и Radiobutton
пример будет таков(больше не знаю) в The last of us есть очень красивые тумблеры кто играл знает
так вот кто знает как сделать тумблер хотя-бы визуально похожий на выше описанный?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тумблер это что-то по типу рычажка? Если да, то как по мне наверное самым простым решением будет создание двух картинок положение выкл. и положение вкл.(вкл. изначально не видно).При нажатии на выкл. убираешь видимость у картинки выкл. и включаешь видимость у вкл. и звук нажатия желательно для полноты картины.

Answer (score 0):

можете попробовать прогресс-бар, для двух положений можно сделать с инвертированием бэкграунда и ползунка. слева - первое положение - фон белый, ползунок - черный. во втором положении - фон черный, ползунок - белый.

Comment: спасибо всем ребята, ваши идеи тоже возьму на заметку!
но я посидел подумал и сделал так:
добавил Scale и разрешил двигаться только на 1 шаг в обе стороны, а потом отслеживать положение
и по действию решать как поступить.